# primeNg calendar unable to disable dates from an array or highlight current Date

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng, primeng-calendar

```js
 {
      "currentTradeDate": "2019-03-12",
      "dateArray": [
        {
          "holidayDate": "2019-12-25"
        },
        {
          "holidayDate": "2019-11-28"
        },
        {
          "holidayDate": "2019-09-02"
        },
        {
          "holidayDate": "2019-07-04"
        },
        ]
```

```html
<p-calendar placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"
      dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [(ngModel)]="value" [disabledDates]="invalidDates" [disabledDays]="[0,6]" name="value" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" (ngModelChange)="selectDate($event)">
    


      <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
        <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (date.day === currDay) ? 'yellow' : 'inherit'}">{{date.day}}</span>
    </ng-template>


    
    </p-calendar>
```

Above is the json response i am getting from an api call. I am putting the holiday date in an array like invalidDates=["2019-12-25","2019-11-28","2019-09-02"]..but i am not able to disable the holiday dates in p-calendar....also i am not able to highlight the currentTradeDate in p-calendar?

invalidDates array  dates needs to be converted into date array?or what?or should i use a different datePicker apart from primeNg.  Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one in your component.ts

```
  let invalidDate = new Date();
  let today = new Date();
  invalidDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
  this.invalidDates = [today,invalidDate];
```